# Does the harvesting time of broccoli sprouts change their glucoraphanin content and sulforaphane formation capacity?

Tags: biochemistry, nutrition, diet, vegetable

Does anybody know if the harvesting time affects glucoraphanin content and sulforaphane formation of broccoli sprouts? Do they also get affected by light exposure or lack of it?

Comment: Welcome to SE biology. This review looks like it has information on at least the light exposure aspect of your question - it might be worth checking it out https://bit.ly/3gkoqPZ

Comment: Thank you for the article. In case, someone else is also interested in this topic, here is the link https://orgprints.org/11395/1/11395.pdf to another study in which researchers compared glucosinolate profiles of different B. oleracea sprouts. To my surprise, the researchers found that red cabbage sprouts contained about twice as must glucoraphanin as broccoli sprouts.